# Sklearn K means Clustering convergence

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to construct clusters out of a set of data using the Kmeans algorithm from `SkLearn`. I want to know how one can determine whether the algorithm actually converged to a solution for one's data.

We feed in the `tol` parameter to define the tolerance for convergence but there is also a `max_iter` parameter that defines the number of iterations the algorithm will do for each run. I get that the algorithm may not always converge within the `max_iter` times of iterations. So is there any attribute or a function that I can access to know if the algorithm converged before the `max_iter` iterations ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have access to the `n_iter_` field of the `KMeans` class, it gets set after you call `fit` (or other routines that internally call `fit`.

Not your fault for overlooking that, it's not part of the documentation, I just found it by checking the source code ;)

Comment: Thank you. I now understand that the documentation is not everything. I will make it a habit to read the source code from now on.

Comment: That is true though.

Answer (score 0):

When I asked the question I was working with the class `KMeans` [http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html].This does not have any function or attribute that allows you to access the `n_iter` of each run of the algorithm. Instead we could use the function `k_means` [http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.k_means.html] instead of the class which has an option that enables returning the best `n_iter`. But this might have its own complications like having to write the `predict` by oneself etc.,